# Cannot connect to Bing Translator API

Tags: api, bing

I have two problem:

1. I cannot not post to MS's server in Ruby.
2. I cannot get result from MS's server.

Following is the details.

Here is my ruby code:(xxxxxx is my client_secret)

```
require "net/http"

base_url = URI("https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13")
params = {:client_id => :woki,
          :client_secret => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          :scope => "http://api.microsofttranslator.com",
          :grant_type => "client_credentials"}

res = Net::HTTP.post_form(base_url, {})

File.open("token", "w").write res.body
```

I hopt to use this code to get my access token.

However, every time an error occurs:

```
rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
```

So, instead, I use bash command curl to post, and a response is returned:

```
{"token_type":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/11/swt-token-profile-1.0","access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","expires_in":"599","scope":"http://api.microsofttranslator.com"}
```

Then, I want to use my access token to translate an English word into Chinese, but still failed. Following is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx" -d "appId&text=apple&to=zh-CHS&from=en&maxTranslations=10" http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/GetTranslations
```

where xxxxx is directly copied from access token above, with something like "http%3a%2f%2f" as is.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512417. I think there is nothing wrong.

However, I only get

```
Error Status Code: 'InternalServerError'

Details: The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the server logs for more details.
```

Who can tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering your parameters -- I see you have 'to' before 'from'.

Also try getting rid of the 'maxTranslations' parameter.